# How can I go about using javascript to output text based on a select attribute?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have three  elements, all of them containing values that should appear in a text area.

The variables are displayed in columns with three rows, A1, B1, C1; A1, B1, C2 etc.

I am trying to out put only the result of the select element, based on the user select. For example: if the user had selected A1 in the first select, B2 in the second and C3 in the third, then the text area would only display the columns that contain A1, B2 and C3. The other values should be removed from the select dropwdown as well.

How do I go about achieving this in jscript?

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>

        <head>

            <meta charset="utf-8">

                    <title>js</title>

        </head>

<body>
<div id = "dropdown">
    <div>
        Select A type <select id="A">
            <option>All</option>
            <option>A1</option>
            <option>A2</option>
            <option>A3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Select B type <select id="B">
            <option>All</option>
            <option>B1</option>
            <option>B2</option>
            <option>B3</option>
            <option>B4</option>
            <option>B5</option>
            <option>B6</option>         
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Select C type 
        <select id="C">
            <option>All</option>
            <option>C1</option>
            <option>C2</option>
            <option>C3</option>
            <option>C4</option>
            <option>C5</option>
            <option>C6</option>
            <option>C7</option>
            <option>C8</option>
            <option>C9</option>
            <option>C10</option>            
        </select>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>A1,B1,C1</div>
    <div>A1,B1,C2</div>
    <div>A1,B1,C3</div>
    <div>A1,B2,C4</div>
    <div>A1,B2,C5</div>
    <div>A1,B3,C6</div>
    <div>A2,B4,C7</div>
    <div>A2,B5,C8</div>
    <div>A2,B5,C9</div>
    <div>A3,B6,C10</div>


    </body>

</html>
```

The idea is to display on the page only entries for the selected options from the dropdown, as well as to remove options that do not match the criteria from it.

For example : After selecting A3 from the dropdown, all but the B6 and C10 values from the dropdown should disappear, and the text output should be A3, B6, C10, as only these entries appear on the same line with A3.

Comment: Start by writing some code that selects elements based on their "selected" state. Then one at a time, update the text area with the value of those elements. If you get stuck somewhere, ask a *specific* question that shows your progress to that point.

Comment: I have added the html as well as more clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a global listener to the wrapping HTML element of all your elements.

This kind of HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="element_target></div>
    <div class="element_target></div>
    <div class="element_target></div>
</div>
```

And then you just add your listener:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", (event) => {

    // Adding the required code to get the value
    if (event.target.classList.contains("element_target") { // Checking if the target element is correct
        console.log(event.target.innerHTML); // Just a dummy to give you the code required to fetch the innerHTML just put it where you need it
    }
});
```

This code should work if I understood your question.

Comment: Not sure, although I would give you an upvote for interest, were I not new to the site. I'll try and see what I get.

Comment: No, it did not, as I'm still looking for a way to remove dropdown options after the selection was made. Thank you very much, though! I have added more details to the post, hopefully this clears it up in regards to what I am trying to do.

Comment: @SmashingQuasar: Your answer only vaguely relates to the question being asked. It's basically showing how to bind an event handler and perform some basic event delegation. If you don't get why you were down voted, read the question again more carefully.

Comment: @squint the original question was incredibly vague and broad and nothing like it is actually. There was absolutely no way to answer it more precisely without the HTML nor JavaScript.

Comment: The original question gave enough information to know that there was more to it than what you were answering. Either way, if you feel there's not enough information to answer with reasonable precision, then don't answer, or at least cover the sparse details that do exist.